# Firewalls (ufw vs apf) on Ubuntu

Tags: security, ssh, firewall, lamp, fail2ban

On my LAMP servers, do either of the firewall interfaces (ufw or apt) allow you to setup rate limiting to automatically ban brute force attempts (e.g. via SSH)? Or, is it best to install fail2ban in conjunction with strict firewall rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `ufw` look into the `limit` command.

```
sudo ufw limit ssh
```

From the `ufw` man page section on the `limit` command:

```
RULE SYNTAX
   [...]

   ufw supports connection rate limiting, which is useful  for  protecting
   against  brute-force  login attacks. ufw will deny connections if an IP
   address has attempted to initiate 6 or more connections in the last  30
   seconds.    See  http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187  for
   details.  Typical usage is:

     ufw limit ssh/tcp
```

Comment: Is this the same functionality of fail2ban's ssh jail?

Comment: @TrentScott Don't know. I don't use fail2ban.

Answer (score 2):

I ALWAYS recommend spending the time to learn how the firewall rules work.

UFW may meet your needs today but it's limited, and it may not do what you need tomorrow and you need it RIGHT NOW.

Spend some quality time with some webpages talking about IPTables (properly called NetFilter). It's time well spent if your setup will be growing in complexity or scope in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`ufw` is not more than an interface to manage netfilter rules. From `man ufw`, you can read:

```
ufw - program for managing a netfilter firewall
```

Several netfilter modules can be used to implement different security measures. Have a look at [this page](http://linuxgazette.net/108/odonovan.html). You can see `limit` and `iplimit` modules. You can find also `recent` module.

[Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is nice as it allows you to block some IPs by modifying your firewall rules. It can scan log files to detect breaking attempts. Also, it can be configured to do an arbitrary action such as alerting you and/or executing some script, etc...